# Golang - unexpected end of stream while inserting data to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, go

I'm currently writing a code in Golang that handles POST requests and store data into the MySQL database.

Here's what I've written so far.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "database/sql"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var myLogger *log.Logger
var db *sql.DB
var err error

type UserRegistrationData struct {
    email string
    password string
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    myLogger = log.New(os.Stdout, "INFO: ", log.LstdFlags)

    var email string = r.PostFormValue("email")
    var password string = r.PostFormValue("password")

    data := UserRegistrationData{email, password}
    jsonEncoded, _ := json.Marshal(data)

    myLogger.Println("Success")

    hashedPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)", email, hashedPassword)
}

func initialiseDB() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/authenticationgolang")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    defer db.Close()
}

func main() {
    initialiseDB()
    http.HandleFunc("/call", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

As I run the code and try to save the data, I keep getting the following message.

`unexpected end of stream on Connection{10.10.10.153:8080, proxy=DIRECT@hostAddress=/10.10.10.153:8080 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}`

The log seems to point out that this line has a problem, and I would like to ask somebody for fixing this out.

`_, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)", email, hashedPassword)`

**Added** Here's the log message I get on the console.

```
2017/05/18 14:47:52 http: panic serving 10.10.10.58:41668: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 20 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc4201360a0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1721 +0xd0
panic(0x1288b60, 0x1424e70)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x14027c0, 0xc420010450, 0xc420034801, 0x10000000142ec80, 0x1600960, 0x2)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:896 +0x3a
database/sql.(*DB).exec(0x0, 0x14027c0, 0xc420010450, 0x12e699d, 0x31, 0xc420045c58, 0x2, 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:1183 +0xb9
database/sql.(*DB).ExecContext(0x0, 0x14027c0, 0xc420010450, 0x12e699d, 0x31, 0xc420045c58, 0x2, 0x2, 0x126ed20, 0xc42013c440, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:1165 +0xbc
database/sql.(*DB).Exec(0x0, 0x12e699d, 0x31, 0xc420034c58, 0x2, 0x2, 0x3c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/database/sql/sql.go:1179 +0x85
main.handler(0x14022c0, 0xc42014a0e0, 0xc420144100)
    /Users/marshall/documents/projects/authenticationgolang/helloworld.go:40 +0x530
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x12ea668, 0x14022c0, 0xc42014a0e0, 0xc420144100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1942 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x142e060, 0x14022c0, 0xc42014a0e0, 0xc420144100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2238 +0x130
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42009a2c0, 0x14022c0, 0xc42014a0e0, 0xc420144100)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2568 +0x92
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc4201360a0, 0x1402780, 0xc42011e580)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0x612
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2668 +0x2ce
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From error message that you got :

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>   goroutine 20 [running]:

Your `db` varible in your `hanlder()` is nil that's the root of the cause.

to fix this you can remove your `:` in your `initialiseDB()`. Because here you are assign to new variable local in the function not to your global variable. Like this :

```
func initialiseDB() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/authenticationgolang")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

***Suggestion***

And then on your code please check the error value returned by the function like :

```
data := UserRegistrationData{email, password}
    jsonEncoded, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if err !=nil {
        myLogger.Fatal(err)
    }

    myLogger.Println("Success")

    hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
       myLogger.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)", email, hashedPassword)
   if err != nil {
       myLogger.Fatal(err)
   }
```

Or you can use `Println()` in case you don't want to stop your application to run like this :

```
if err != nil {
   myLogger.Println(err)
   return
}
```

The return will stop the execution of the code. Using this approach you will notice if somethings error happens on your server side and you know which line the error happened.

And don't forget to send your response if the request success like :

```
resp := struct {
    Message string
}{
    Message : "your message",
}

// Write the response
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm struggling with the code. I added the log to the question, and can you please check that out?

Comment: Yes I just checked out your answer and reflected it to my code. It's working fine and thanks for your help! :)